# YARN + how to debug wget

Tags: linux, networking, http, wget, hadoop

we are testing with `wget` VIA port `8088` the connection from `ResourceManager02` to `ResourceManager01`

- both Resource Managers are part of YARN service , and each resource manager service installed on RHEL 7.9 version

as the following

```
wget http://ResourceManager01.ggtp:8088
--2023-02-22 16:55:36--  http://ResourceManager01.ggtp:8088/
Resolving ResourceManager01.ggtp (ResourceManager01.ggtp)... 182.55.190.78
Connecting to ResourceManager01.ggtp (ResourceManager01.ggtp)|182.55.190.78|:8088... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 307 TEMPORARY_REDIRECT
Location: http://ResourceManager01.ggtp:8088/ [following]
--2023-02-22 16:55:36--  http://ResourceManager01.ggtp:8088/
Resolving ResourceManager01.ggtp (ResourceManager01.ggtp)... 182.55.190.85
Connecting to ResourceManager01.ggtp (ResourceManager01.ggtp)|182.55.190.85|:8088... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://ResourceManager01.ggtp:8088/cluster [following]
--2023-02-22 16:57:49--  http://ResourceManager01.ggtp:8088/cluster
Reusing existing connection to ResourceManager01.ggtp:8088.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

    [ <=>                                                                                                                                                                                                ] 5,343,472   --.-K/s   in 0.1s

2023-02-22 16:58:43 (40.0 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [5343472]


You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
```

as we can see above we have errors as  `HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found`

and actually the connection take 2-3 min instead of 1 second

is it possible to debug this behavior , and why `wget` not reached the connection to machine - `ResourceManager01` ?

we are perform this testing because we have problem about the connection between secondary `ResourceManager02` to primary resources manager - `ResourceManager01`,

both resources manager are part of Hadoop cluster ( HDP 2.6.5 version )

and from Ambari UI we get the following alert

```
Connection failed to http://ResourceManager01.ggtp:8088 (timed out)
```